# Alignment issue with child div inside the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have div(class name:xyz)to insert small 4 divs (class name:ax )in it.
I need to insert the first two divs vertically, the third one should come next to first one horizontally and the fourth one should come next to the third vertically.
But all the children are appearing vertically in side the  parent.

```css
.xyz {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.ax {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 50px 25px 0;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe all you want is to be divs displayed as 1,3 and 2,4 in next row fashion. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 Multiple column layout which in your case will be `column-count: 2;`, this property works in *[following browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)*.

```css
.xyz {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 500px;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
}

.ax {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 50px 25px 0;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="ax">1</div>
  <div class="ax">2</div>
  <div class="ax">3</div>
  <div class="ax">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps worth warning about browsers compatibility? http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```css
.xyz {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.ax {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 50px 25px 0;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will align all the div vertically if the max-width is increased

Comment: This places the divs `[1,2][3,4]`, when OP is looking for `[1,3][2,4]`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.xyz {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.ax {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 50px 25px 0;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
  <div class="ax"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This places the divs `[1,2][3,4]`, when OP is looking for `[1,3][2,4]`

Comment: Oh yeah, I reversed the vertical haha

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one , try with snippet

```css
.xyz {
  max-height: 450px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-right: -25px; /* newly added */
  margin-left: -25px; /* newly added */
}

.ax {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 25px 25px 25px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  float:left; /* newly added */
}
```

```html
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="ax">1 </div>
  <div class="ax">2 </div>
  <div class="ax">3 </div>
  <div class="ax">4 </div>
</div>
```